# Is there any plan to create a Squarespace integration for CiviCRM?

Tags: integration

sorry if this info is already available elsewhere but couldn't find it on the CiviCRM website or on here. I'm really hoping to use Squarespace for my organisation's website to make it as simple as possible for other people to make changes without breaking things/making them hideous. I know there is no Squarespace integration at the moment, but am wondering if this is something that might be in the pipeline given their increasing market share. I'm aware that we can do a Wordpress site to sit alongside the public Squarespace site to handle the Civi integration, but I don't have confidence that I could do this myself and we currently have zero (0) funding, so wouldn't be able to pay a Civi partner to do it until well into the future. Thank you for all your incredible work from a long-time Civi fan.

Comment: Hi Kristin and welcome. I v much doubt it is on any long term plans. i think the most applicable long-term plan would be if CiviCRM ever becomes a standalone platform again. there are some active conversations at the moment (for first time in some years as i recall) but i doubt anyone could give you a viable date for this. Happy to point you at the thread on it but it is fairly technical at this point

Comment: It isn't too difficult  to do some basic stuff with Squarespace & Civi - I set up donations and newsletter requests to come to Civi through a Squarespace website. BTW, the Squarespace website was really good, then the client ditched it for a website that was slightly better but cost far, far more, with no Civi integration... such is life

Comment: did that site also have a front-end of drupal or wordpress, Andy, and then you were using remote form or other options (exposed profiles) to show on squarespace

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thank you both for your response! that is very helpful to know. i ended up trying to install on wordpress without success and am absolutely tearing my hair out. i love civi and really want to use it but there might just be too many technical hurdles :/

Comment: what sort of hosting platform were you trying to set it up on?

Comment: thanks @petednz-fuzion, after a great deal of stress and time I've managed to get Civi plugin working on wordpress w VPS via Dreamhost. It has been a llooot of googling, a llooot of trial and error, a llooot of setting up new services and a llloooot of contacting support through my hosting provider, but slowly slowly i am getting there. am working through the configuration tasks bit by bit and no doubt will have more questions coming.

Comment: well done. could you +1/accept the answer below so SE knows it has been answered. thx

Comment: Done – I think? Thank you! Let me know if I clicked the wrong thing @petednz-fuzion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SquareSpace integration is not in any pipeline that I am aware of. The most common approach currently would be to set up civicrm on WP or Drupal as the admin access CMS. then use Remote Forms or other methods for embedding forms on external sites.

There are discussions that have reignited recently about civicrm working as a standalone crm which can be seen [here](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/wtjng5tkgtb6jqmbh11f8rf6za)